# Changing the name of the review option from "Leave Open" to "Remove from Review"

Tags: feature-request, review

Over at Blender SE, we had a [question](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/927/8262) on meta regarding the "Leave Open" review option for the close vote stack. The user was confused about what it actually did.

The answer is that it simply is a vote to remove it from the review stack. Saying keep open is very misleading. It implies that clicking the button votes against the close votes, or something of that nature. While it does indirectly do that, that's not what clicking the button actually does. It actually votes to remove it from the stack.

I think a better wording would be "Remove from Review", or something similar to that. There could then be a tooltip explaining a little bit more about what it does in case there is any confusion. Maybe something like "Votes to remove this from the close vote queue, requires three votes".

Comment: Did you mean queue? Because last I heard a queue and a stack were two completely different data structures.

Comment: Surely you mean "remove from review". "Remove from stack" implies it's going to be deleted from the site itself.

Comment: Sure. I'm giving a suggestion which I'm perfectly fine with being edited. I'm just trying to raise awareness.

Comment: It doesn't *only* remove it from review. It also starts the aging process on the existing close votes immediately. So a question with four close votes on it could have zero close votes on it four days later. While review doesn't immediately invalidate all the close votes at once, it does expedite the process of making them go away.

Comment: Ah, okay. That's probably enough for the current name/tooltip to be good enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, right now it's "Leave Open", not "Keep Open", and it makes perfect sense. One knows that choosing this means "I want to leave this question open".

"Remove From Review" might be technically correct, but less intuitive. It can be also changed "Vote to Remove From the Close Votes Review Queue" but as you might figure, it just becomes too long.

Better have short and simple button  caption, and those who want extra details and guidance, can go to the help center and the per meta site to read the review faq.

Comment: Well, I don't really see how it would be seen that way. But above it was suggested for it to instead be "remove from review" which I think is a better way to put it.

Comment: So you can click "edit" and change. Still, I think "Leave Open" is short, simple, and makes perfect sense.

Comment: BTW, I explained the problem with Leave open in my post. It can easily be misunderstood as "vote against close votes" when that's not what it does at all, even if it does indirectly effect the amount of close votes.

Comment: @TARDISMaker That is actually what I thought until this question came up

Comment: Edited answer per question edit. /cc @TARDISMaker.

Comment: I get your point. Maybe it would be better to make the tooltip more descriptive instead of "disagree with close vote"? Is your suggestion of "Vote to remove from close votes review queue" too long for a tooltip? I know this would be going against the naming convention found in the close queue, but I think it would be worth it.

Comment: Apparently the button also makes the close votes start to age away, so I've now officially have a good enough reason why the current one is fine.

Answer (score 2):

The *Remove from Stack* is even more confusing than you say the current naming is. Often people refer to Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange when they say *Stack*. The name you propose is very confusing to me.

The current naming is clear. This is certainly true when you consider the words before it:

> This question has been flagged for ... [Leave Open] ...

The *Leave Open* points to *This question*. This is clear in my opinion. Let's keep it this way.

Comment: No, it makes people think that they're directly voting against the close votes. There's a comment just below saying that they thought that that's what it did until they saw this. btw, I just edited to change it from stack to review, hopefully that's more clear.

Comment: *Leave question open* better? That is how I read it.

Comment: What difference does that make? It still reads as voting against close votes.